# Has anyone installed Indigo on the rpi 2?

Tags: raspberrypi

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I got my rpi 2 yesterday and was wondering if the guide for installing indigo on the original rpi would work?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/203787/has-anyone-installed-indigo-on-the-rpi-2?/) by [Mr. CEO](https://answers.ros.org/users/21719/mr.-ceo/) on ROS Answers with karma: 143 on 2015-02-25

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [marguedas](https://answers.ros.org/users/19307/marguedas/) on 2015-02-27**:
I just received mine and didn't have time to try yet but I would be very interested if you find an easy/convenient way to do it!

Seems that this is working: http://wiki.ros.org/ROSberryPi/Installing%20ROS%20Indigo%20on%20Raspberry%20Pi
I'll give it a try in a few weeks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Yes, the guide works. Make sure to install all the patches it mentions. It took a day or do to get a fully working installation.

I have ROS indigo working on the Pi 2B, including rviz. I'm still working on installing Gazebo and PCL.

If there is a suitable place to post it, I'm happy to post the complete OS image to save everyone a lot of time.

Simon

---

Originally posted by [SimonB](https://answers.ros.org/users/21874/simonb/) with karma: 88 on 2015-03-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [yuwang](https://answers.ros.org/users/22343/yuwang/) on 2015-05-13**:
have you post your image? I took a lot time but the rviz still not work, while the other  packages works fine. if you post your image on somewhere, please let me know, thanks.

yuwang